# Простой маршрутизатор 3-х сетей из Linux

Tags: маршрутизация, linux

Доброго времени суток. Есть такая задача поставить компьютер с 3-мя сетевыми картами, в которые идут 3 разные сети:

1. 10.11.0.0/16
2. 172.20.0.0/16
3. 192.168.1.0/24

Ни одна сеть не должна видеть другую сеть, но админские компьютеры (*например* 10.11.10.7) должны видеть другие сети по всем портам.

Как мне это сделать через iptables ? Я уже просто окончательно запутался.

P.S.сетевые карты:

eth0: 10.11.20.70

eth1: 172.20.1.1

eth2: 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ИМХО самое простейшее - не делать этот комп шлюзом по умолчании. На компах адинистраторов прорписать route add для подсетей, указав этот комп в качестве роутера. Другие просто не будут знать, что так можно ходить ;)

Comment: отлично сейчас сбросил всё с iptablesДобавил на компьютере админа (WinXP) route ADD 172.20.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.11.20.70толку нет все равно он не видит компьютер из другой сети, в моём случае 172.20.1.2. Может я что-то не так сделал, или не сделал ?

Comment: @skykub, Хотя нет всё нормально. Я только пинговал и больше ничего не делал, а на самом деле всё остальное работает. Так даже лучше. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если делать тупо то ставьте на писюк линукс Ubuntu/CentOS/FreeBSD что вам ближе. Ставьте три сетевые карточки (если есть управляемый коммутатор который у меет VLAN'ы 802.1q я бы сдела на vlan'ах) на каждый сетевой интерфейс вешайте по ip-адресу из каждой сети. Например: 10.11.0.1/16172.20.0.1/16192.168.1.1/24

Включите пересылку пакетов между интерфейсами [How to Enable IP Forwarding in Linux](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/)

Далее настраиваем iptables [Iptables Stateful Firewall and NAT Routing](http://fabiobaltieri.com/2011/09/12/iptables-firewall-nat/)

Как настроить vlan'ы [HowTo: Configure Linux Virtual Local Area Network (VLAN)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-linux-virtual-local-area-network-vlan.html) как преимущество нужна только одна сетевая карта.

Comment: @huffman, то что надо 3 сетевые карты я знаю. Я извиняюсь забыл дописать настройки сетевых карт. Но как iptables настроить я все равно не понял.

Comment: Что по iptables вам не понятно?

Comment: как мне запретить любые соединения и форвадинги к сервере  и разрешить  админскому компьютеру подключаться например через Radmin к компьютерам других сетей.

Comment: Включаем пересылку пакетов ipv4 echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Comment: Запрещаем всеiptables -P INPUT DROPразрешаем все для интерфейса loiptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPTразрешаем трафик для из сети 192.168.0.0/24 через интерфейс eth0iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

Comment: @huffman, мне не надо разрешать трафик для сети 192.168.0.0. пускай компьютеры в этой сети крутятся (в хабе) но дальше сервера не лезут. Надо наоборот чтобы 10.11.10.7 мог видеть эту сеть а они другие сети нет.

Comment: ну поменяйте сеть 192.168.0.0 на адрес 10.11.10.7 и все. Делайте по аналогии. Почитайте документацию по iptables она уже давно переведена вся на русский, полно примеров.

Comment: @huffman, сделал но всё равно нет эффекта. Никто ни кого не видит и дальше

Answer (score 0):

Для удобства общения с iptables использую Shorewall - там лексика построения правил менее запутанная. После конфигурирования и запуска Shorewall пропишет правила в iptables.
[Shorewall](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shorewall)